# VBA code to copy rows from one excel sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

The original spreadsheet was from column A to E. I just pasted the numbers in column F from another sheet. My new spreadsheet has 1517 rows and goes from columns A-H. The numbers in column F (row 2 to row 420) are also in column C.

I was able to use the MATCH function of Excel to find the exact position of a number in column C i.e In column C, on which row can I find the numbers that are in column F? For instance, the number "12345678910" in cell F2 can be found in cell C1049,on row 1049. I put those position numbers in a column that I called "index".

Now, the goal is to write a vba code to copy those rows at once. I am trying to extract/copy to another sheet the numbers in column F that are also in column C but I only want columns A to E - from the original sheet. Copy each row number that is in the index column but only the columns A-E. To be clear, "12345678910" is also in cell C1049. "Copy row 1049 from column A-E" and do that for each position number in the index column.

I cannot sort the spreadsheet because the columns A-E are linked. A sort would alter the information. Any help would be appreciated.

A sample of my spreadsheet

Comment: Please use paragraphs...

Comment: If your end goal is to sort, just select all cells in your excel spreadsheet and hit CTRL+C then (hold ALT) and tap E+S+V and hit enter in that order, and it'll replace the contents with the live values instead of the formulas. Still works on excel 2013

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub filterCopy()

   Dim ws1 As Worksheet
   Dim ws2 As Worksheet

   Set ws1 = Sheet1
   Set ws2 = Sheet2

   ws1.Range("A1:F1517").AutoFilter 6, "<>"
   ws1.Range("A1:F1517").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws2.Range("A1")

End Sub
```